# How to filter Groups by Distribution List Email using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to run a query that pulls back any groups that match the given email.

This will be ultimately used to expand a DL's members given an email.

```
var emailAddress = "test@email.com"
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var group = await graphClient
    .Groups
    .Request()
    .Filter($"mail+eq+{emailAddress}")
    .GetAsync();
```

I expect that the query will run without error on the filter and either return a group with said email or if none are found use the default behavior of the api.

However, it currently breaks on the filter query.

Comment: Can you please post your complete solution including how you're setting auth provider and so on? I'm also trying to expand a distribution list email address to retrieve email addresses inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are getting `Invalid filter clause` exception, `emailAddress` value in [filter expression](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/overview/query_parameters#filter)  needs to be enclosed in single quotes like this:

```
 var groups = await graphClient
                .Groups
                .Request()
                .Filter($"mail+eq+'{emailAddress}'")
                .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Correct. Thank you sir!

Comment: with HTTP request with same filter returns 1 group. but when I use the SDK like this answer, I get no results and no error.